# Zend 2 escaping single-quote

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db, laminas

I am using Zend Framework 2 to generate the following escaped single-quote SQL query,

```
SELECT
    `document`.*
FROM
    `document`
WHERE
    (
        `document`.`document_taxon` LIKE '%Men\'s Health %' --escaped quote
        AND `document`.`document_source_id` = ' 5 '
        AND `document`.`document_published` = ' 1 '
        AND `document`.`document_deleted` = ' 0 '
    )
ORDER BY
    `document_id` DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

But I am getting this instead,

```
SELECT
    `document`.*
FROM
    `document`
WHERE
    (
        `document`.`document_taxon` LIKE '%Men's Health%'
        AND `document`.`document_source_id` = ' 5 '
        AND `document`.`document_published` = ' 1 '
        AND `document`.`document_deleted` = ' 0 '
    )
ORDER BY
    `document_id` DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

And here is my code

```
class DocumentTable extends TableGateway
{
    ....
    $select=$this->getSql()->select();                                                                                 
    $select->columns(array('*'));
    $select->where
        ->NEST
        ->like('document_taxon', '%' . $label . '%')
        ->and
        ->equalTo('document_source_id', $sourceId)
        ->and
        ->equalTo('document_published', true)
        ->and
        ->equalTo('document_deleted', 0)
        ->UNNEST;

    $select->order('document_id DESC');
    $select->limit($limit);
    $select->offset($offset);
    ...
}
```

I tried,

- `$this->getAdapter()->getPlatform()->quoteValue($string)`
- `\Zend\Db\Sql\Expression("%". $label . "%")`
- `str_replace("'", "\'", $label)`

But I didn’t have much luck. I welcome any suggestion to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. I was passing a **normalized** “label” value instead of the raw value. The above code snippet works fine.